# Call .java file from .html file in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

Its working fine in android 8, Page is redirecting but in higher SDK versions  like android 2.3.3 API level 10, the application simply exit on-click the redirecting-link.

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_height="189dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      private WebView mainWebView = null;
      Boolean javascriptInterfaceBroken;

      @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xml);            

        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        mainWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new nextpage(this), "Android");
      }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

html file:

```
<body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening" >Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <a href="javascript:Android.launchActivity()">cordova</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
</body>
```

Another class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class nextpage {
    private Context context;

    public nextpage(Context context) {    
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void launchActivity() {
        context.startActivity(new Intent((Activity)context,deal.class)); 
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
01-28 11:48:58.287: D/dalvikvm(4093): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 53% free 2576K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 47ms
01-28 11:48:59.347: D/szipinf(4093): Initializing inflate state
01-28 11:48:59.347: D/szipinf(4093): Initializing zlib to inflate
01-28 11:49:06.657: W/dalvikvm(4093): JNI WARNING: jarray 0x4058fa70 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510790 self=0x1f9650
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093):   | sysTid=4102 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2071192
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093):   | schedstat=( 1354713686 909395665 294 )
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
01-28 11:49:06.667: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53)
01-28 11:49:06.677: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
01-28 11:49:06.677: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 11:49:06.677: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 11:49:06.677: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
01-28 11:49:06.677: I/dalvikvm(4093):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-28 11:49:06.677: E/dalvikvm(4093): VM aborting
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Why tell us you have a problem and then not describe the problem?

Comment: Ditto to what Simon said, please provide the error trace and relevant log messages and so on (and what it appears you're trying to do is use the JavaScript interface on API level >= 10, not "call .java file" -- there is no .java at runtime, that might be confusing people too -- and I'd edit the question, but I'm not quite sure myself exactly what the issue/error is).

Comment: @CharlieCollins the application exit when i run the file in api level >=10

Comment: @Simon the application exit when i run the file in api level >=10

Comment: Then please post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @Simon nothing is displaying in Logcat ,the application simply exit

Comment: That can only happen if you call finish() or System.exit() - and logcat is never empty.  You need to look again.

Comment: @Simon i have attached the logcat error